# Toggle keeps switching off in RSelenium

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am using RSelenium to scrape this website: https://www.derstandard.at/story/2000138736389/doskozil-fordert-ende-des-omv-gashandels-an-der-boerse.

Specifically, I want to expand all replies in the comment section by clicking the gearwheel button at the beginning of the comment section, then selecting the second toggle "Antworten ausgeklappt". This works, but when I close the settings menu and open it again, the toggle is again default off.

It stays on when I click the toggle manually, even when refreshing the page. This would be my goal to manage via Rselenium.

Since the comment section HTML is behind a shadow root, I am using javascript in R to click the buttons.
I tried the following:

```
# Find the element that contains the shadow root
shadow_host <- driver$findElement(using="xpath", value='//*[@id="story-community"]/div/div[2]/dst-forum')

# access the shadow root and click the settings button
driver$executeScript(
  "const shadowRoot = arguments[0].shadowRoot;
  const button = shadowRoot.querySelector('#flyout-trigger-forum-settings-flyout');
  button.click();",
  list(shadow_host)
)

# click toggle
driver$executeScript(
  "const shadowRoot = arguments[0].shadowRoot;
  const toggle = shadowRoot.querySelector('#forum--toggle-threads');
  toggle.click();",
  list(shadow_host)
)
```

The above code activates the toggle as intended, but it keeps snapping back when I refresh the page or close the settings menu.

I also tried:

```
driver$executeScript(
  "const shadowRoot = arguments[0].shadowRoot;
  const toggle = shadowRoot.querySelector('#forum--toggle-threads');
  toggle.checked = !toggle.checked;
  toggle.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true })); ",
  list(shadow_host)
)
```

but this doesn't even activate the toggle. Nor does this:

```
driver$executeScript(
  "var shadowRoot = arguments[0].shadowRoot;
  var element = shadowRoot.querySelector('#forum--toggle-threads');
  var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window
  });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);",
  list(shadow_host)
  )
```

I realised when I hover manually over the toggle, a shadow appears. When I activate it via code, there is no shadow effect, no clue though if this is useful information.